# Dynamically add array elements to JSON Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm creating a JSON object from an array and I want to dynamically push data to this JSON object based on the values from array. See my code for a better understanding of my problem...

```
for(i=0;i<duplicates.length; i++) {
  var request = {
    "name": duplicates[i].scope,
    "id": 3,
    "rules":[
      {
        "name": duplicates[i].scope + " " + "OP SDR Sync",
        "tags": [
          {
            "tagId": 1,
            "variables":[
              {
                "variable": duplicates[i].variable[j],
                "matchType": "Regex",
                "value": duplicates[i].scopeDef
              }
            ],
            "condition": false,
          },
          {
            "tagId": 1,
            "condition": false,
          }
        ],
        "ruleSetId": 3,
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I take object properties from the `duplicates` array that can have the following elements:

`[{scopeDef=.*, scope=Global, variable=[trackingcode, v1, v2]}, {scopeDef=^https?://([^/:\?]*\.)?delta.com/products, scope=Products Section, variable=[v3]}]`

As you can see, an object contain `variable` element that can have multiple values. I need to push to the JSON object all those values dynamically (meaning that there could be more than 3 values in an array).

For example, after I push all the values from the `duplicates` array, my JSON object should look like this:

```
name=Products Section, 
  rules=
  [
    {
      name=Products Section OP SDR Sync, 
      tags=[
      {
         variables=
         [
           {
             matchType=Regex, 
             variable=v3, 
             value=^https?://([^/:\?]*\.)?delta.com/products
           },
           {
             matchType=Regex, 
             variable=trackingcode, 
             value=.*
           },
           {
             matchType=Regex, 
             variable=v1, 
             value=.*
           },
           {
             matchType=Regex, 
             variable=v2, 
             value=.*
           }
         ], 
         condition=false, 
       }, 
       {
         condition=false, 
         tagId=1
       }
     ], 
     ruleSetId=3
   }
  ]
}
```

I tried the following code but without success:

```
  for(var j in duplicates[i].variable) {
    var append = JSON.parse(request);
    append['variables'].push({
      "variable":duplicates[i].variable[j],
      "matchType": "Regex",
      "value": duplicates[i].scopeDef
    })
  }
```

Please let me know if I need to provide additional information, I just started working with JSON objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you dont need to parse request, you already create an object, parse only when you get JSON as string, like:

```
var json='{"a":"1", "b":"2"}';
var x = JSON.parse(json);
```

Next, you have any property of object wrapped in arrays. To correctly work with it you should write:

```
request.rules[0].tags[0].variables.push({
  "variable":duplicates[i].variable[j],
  "matchType": "Regex",
  "value": duplicates[i].scopeDef
})
```

If you want to use your code snippet, you need some changes in request:

```
  var request = {
"name": duplicates[i].scope,
"id": 3,
"variables":[
   {
   "variable": duplicates[i].variable[j],
   "matchType": "Regex",
   "value": duplicates[i].scopeDef
   }
           ],
"rules":[
  {
    "name": duplicates[i].scope + " " + "OP SDR Sync",
    "tags": [
      {
        "tagId": 1,
        "condition": false,
      },
      {
        "tagId": 1,
        "condition": false,
      }
    ],
    "ruleSetId": 3,
  }
]
}
}
```

To understand JSON remember basic rule: read JSON backward. It means:

- property
- object.property
- arrayOfObfects['id'].object.property
- mainObject.arrayOfObfects['id'].object.property

and so on. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for helping me. Can you also tell me what are the `variables`, `tags` and `tagId` ? Objects?

Comment: In your original code : variables - array of objects, tags - array of objects, tagId - variable (actualy - property of object which is first elementt in array 'tags', which is first element in array rules which is property of object request)