# How can I append a new property to JS object

Tags: javascript

Here is my JS object:

```
  var request = {
    "name": "Name",
    "id": 3,
    "rules":[
      {
        "name": "Rule name",
        "tags": [
          {
            "tagId": 1,
            "variables":[
              {
                "variable": "var1",
                "matchType": "Regex"
              }
            ],
            "condition": false,
          }
        ],
        "ruleSetId": 3,
      }
    ]
  }
```

How can I add a new property `"value": "some value"` to the `variables` objects? For example, after I add this property, the object should look like this:

```
  var request = {
    "name": "Name",
    "id": 3,
    "rules":[
      {
        "name": "Rule name",
        "tags": [
          {
            "tagId": 1,
            "variables":[
              {
                "variable": "var1",
                "matchType": "Regex",
                "value": "some value"   <----------
              }
            ],
            "condition": false,
          }
        ],
        "ruleSetId": 3,
      }
    ]
  }
```

I tried the following but it adds me an additional object that only contains `{"value": "some value"}` :

```
  request.rules[0].tags[0].variables.push({
    "value": "some value"
  });
```

Comment: request.rules[0].tags[0].variables[0].value = "some value"

Comment: Why don't you just learn some basics instead of asking every little question that you might stumble upon? ([1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096937/how-to-push-data-to-a-nested-object), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38098697/empty-element-is-added-to-object), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096415/dynamically-add-array-elements-to-json-object))

Comment: And can people please stop perpetuating these questions by answering. It harms the quality of the site.

Comment: @str you're right but I have a complex code and sometimes is harder for me finding the solution, in addition I'm new working with JSON objects but now I think that I understand the basics

Comment: "JSON objects " JSON is a text format to serialize javascript objects. What you have here is not even a json it is plain old javascript. You definitely need to learn some basics.

Comment: Thank you for providing me additional explanations, I agree with you that I need to learn the basics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
request.rules[0].tags[0].variables[0].value = "some value";
```

Or if you want to append this new property in all variables:

```
var target = 'value';

for (var i = 0; i < request.rules[0].tags[0].variables.length; i++) { 
  if (request.rules[0].tags[0].variables[i][target]) { 
    break;
  }
}

request.rules[0].tags[0].variables[i][target] = "some value";
```

Comment: Append to the `variables` array, or add to each object in the `variables` array?

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
request.rules[0].tags[0].variables[0].value = "some value";
```

Answer (score 0):

`0` is to select the index of the array.

Hope this will be useful

```
var _pushKey = request.rules[0].tags[0].variables[0].value="some value"
```

[`JSFIDDLE`](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/y5wcwh57/)

Comment: `_pushKey` appears to have no purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this:

request.rules[0].tags[0].variables[0]["value"] = "some value";

Comment: How does this solve the problem? Be more specific

Answer (score 0):

```
request.rules[0].tags[0].variables[0].value = "some value";
```

If you want to understand why it works like that then you have to what `{}` and `[]` means in json. 1st one is for object and later is used for array. So you can see that your `request` object has a property named `rules` which is an array of object. `tags` and `variables` property are same as `rules`. then lastly you need to assign new key value for 1st obj in `variables` array that's why variable[0] is used.

Answer (score 0):

you should do this.

```
request.rules[0].tags[0].variables[0]['value'] = 'some value';
```

The object you want add property to is in an array, it's the array's first element. you can achieve this object by `request.rules[0].tags[0].variables[0]`.

Comment: As if six identical answers were not enough already.

Comment: Before I post this answer, I didn't know.

Comment: "I didn't know" First answer identical to yours was posted like 15 minutes before yours. :)

Comment: ok,my bad. I was interrupt by other things.

Answer (score 0):

example:

```
var jsonObj = {
members: 
       {
        host: "hostName"
    }
}
var i;
for(i=4; i<=8; i++){
    var newUser = "user" + i;
    var newValue = "value" + i;
    jsonObj.members[newUser] = newValue ;
}
var str =JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
console.log(str);
console.log(jsonObj);
```

in your case: request.rules[0].tags[0].variables[value] = 'some value';

Comment: That example doesn't have much relevance to the question.

Comment: yes, but i think he get idea batter idea using this example

Comment: And `variables[0].value`.

Answer (score -1):

You're almost there.

```
request.rules[0].tags[1].variables['value'] = 'some value';
```

Comment: `tags[0]`, surely?

Comment: And `variables[0].value`.